# Trigger animation when scrolling past element using iScroll.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iscroll

I'm using [iScroll.js](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) on a project and I'd like to trigger an animation when scrolling past a `<div>`. I'm a little bit lost as to how to do it, as using iScroll means [Waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) doesn't work.

```
 overlayScroll = new IScroll('.overlay', { mouseWheel: true });

 overlayScroll.on('scrollStart', scrollFn);

 function scrollFn(){
     //do something
 };
```

This makes my actions happen when I scroll on top of the `.overlay`, but I need it to only start after reaching a certain point inside the `.overlay`. I also want to be able to detect direction so I can reverse the actions if the user scrolls up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.